# Request access to nearby Oracle database, need update statement (ora-01031)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I've got

```
url:  jdbc:oracle:thin:@195.123.456.789:1521:someSID
User: artem
Password: unchangeableForAllUsers
```

I'm also got second DB, all the same, changing only the name

```
url:  jdbc:oracle:thin:@195.123.456.789:1521:someSID
User: denis
Password: unchangeableForAllUsers
```

How can I make update query from one DB to other? Using pl/sql I've got next message from Web-browser, when I try to change artem.table to denis.table:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>
> SQL Statement ignored

When I try to save changes in artem pl/sql package(query to denis db, like that

> ```
> update denis.table dt
> set dt.someColumn=1
> where dt.ID=3305;
> ```

), see next in my IDE:

> PL/SQL ORA-00942: User table or view does not exist

While I'm in IDE, logged like artem, I can to change and commit other users db  free, from IDE SQL console.. maybe couse they have the same url and password? How can I save my query

> ```
> update denis.table dt
> set dt.someColumn=1
> where dt.ID=3305;
> ```

in artem package for get access(update cell) to nearby database from Web-site, when i logged there like artem.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code of your stored procedure? Note that those aren't "two databases", those are two different _schemas_ in the same database (at least if your JDBC URLs are correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described, this is not a jdbc or plsql issue but rather a permissions issue.

You are connecting to the same database, but as two different users. In Oracle, a user has their own schema (same name as the user). If you wish to access data in schema A from schema B, schema A must GRANT permissions to schema B.

For example, if you want the user "artem" to have permission to UPDATE table "mytable" in schema "denis", log into the account "denis" and GRANT UPDATE permission to "artem":

```
-- While logged in as "denis"
GRANT UPDATE ON mytable TO artem;
```

Now you can log in as "artem" and query "denis.mytable".  Grants you may want to give: `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`.  This, of course, works both ways (if you want user "denis" to have access to "artem" objects, then "artem" must GRANT permission to "denis".